# $f$ is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable w.r.t $g$ iff $f$ is a.e. continuous w.r.t the measure induced by $g$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, stieltjes-integral

> Suppose that $g$ is a monotone function on $[a,b]$ and $f$ is a
>   bounded function defined on $[a,b]$. Show that $f$ is
>   Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to $g$ if and only if $f$ is
>   almost everywhere continuous with respect to the measure induced by
>   $g$

I'm trying to imagine what could possibly fail if we found a set of non-zero measure w.r.t to $m_g$ (the measure induced by $g$). I'm picturing that if such a set were to be found, then it would be impossible to find a partition that makes $\mathrm{U}(f,g,P) - \mathrm{L}(f,g,P) < \epsilon$ for a given $\epsilon>0$ because there will be a gap inside the interval $[a,b]$ that's too big and our partitioning will fail to cover that in an appropriate way. But I don't know how to write this down rigorously. I also don't know how the measure induced by $g$ looks like and I have asked a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2531808/assuming-g-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-is-monotone-what-is-the-pullback-measur).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you defining $m_g$ on intervals?

Comment: @zhw.: That's actually the main problem here preventing me from proceeding. The book hasn't mentioned what it means by the measure induced by $g$. I tried to consider some rather simple choices like $\mu_g([s,t])=g(t)-g(s)$ for when $g$ is increasing. But I'm not sure whether it is actually the measure meant by the problem or not. I'm trying to work with that definition because it seems to be simple and extend well to the Stieltjes integral of $f$.

Comment: Have you seen the proof of this for $g(x) = x?$ Here $m_g$ is just Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @zhw: Not yet but I found the proof for the Riemann case after you suggested. :) It seems that if our measure is indeed defined like that, then a generalization to Stieltjes case is possible but some technicalities have to be checked and I'm not sure about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, the proof of this fact has been published as an article titled  *Riemann-Stieltjes and Lebesgue-Stieltjes Integrability* by  H. J. Ter Horst  in  *The American Mathematical Monthly*. Please check Theorem C of the aforementioned article.

The DOI of the article is [10.2307/2323739](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2323739) and it can be accessed online for free on [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2323739).