# Assuming $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is monotone, what is the pullback measure of $g$ w.r.t to the Lebesgue measure on the domain?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I haven't had a course in measure theory yet, so if something I say doesn't make sense, please let me know. This isn't a homework question, rather a question about the machinery and concepts of measure theory for my own better understanding.

So, suppose that $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a monotone function and $\mathbb{R}$ has been equipped with the Lebesgue measure, naturally.

I want to use $g$ to induce a new measure on $\mathbb{R}$. The definition goes like this:

> If $(X,\Sigma_1, \mu)$ and $(Y,\Sigma_2)$ are two measure spaces and
>   $f: X \to Y$ is a measurable function, we can induce a measure on $Y$
>   by setting: $$\mu_f(A)=\mu(f^{-1}(A))$$

So, what I want to know as a curiosity whether it's possible that this definition can be expressed as an integral of $g$ in some way. For example, I noticed that when $\mathrm{m}$ is the Lebesgue measure, we can express $\mathrm{m}(A)$ as:

$$\mathrm{m}(A) = \int_A 1.\mathrm{d}x$$

Is it possible to find a similar integral expression for $\mu_f(A)$? If yes, how does it look like? Does it look like

$$\mu_f(A) = \int_A g(x)\mathrm{d}x$$

or a similar expression?

Moreover, do we really need $g$ to be monotone? or can it be generalized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mu_{f}(A)=\displaystyle\int_{\bf{R}}\chi_{f^{-1}(A)}(x)dx$. This is something like the distribution in probability: For random variable $X$, the distribution $\mu_{X}$ is such that $\mu_{X}(\varphi)=\displaystyle\int\varphi\circ X(\omega)dP(\omega)$.

Comment: I use $f$ throughout.

Comment: I actually did consider that representation, but I'm looking for something less trivial. I had to mention it in the question, sorry. However, would you explain the second part? It does look like something I'm looking for. I'm working on a problem and the second part seems relevant.

Comment: You may search for the definition of distribution of a random variable, a book that I will recommend is: Probability and Stochastics, by Erhan Cinlar.